# swift: can not select annotation in code

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Good morning everybody.

Sorry to ask for this but how do you select an annotation in code using swift.
I have read the documentation and it says that it is better not to call ".selected" directly. Indeed, when I modify the .selected property of an annotation programmatically, the callout is not shown.

I can select any annotation by clicking on it but not in code.

Thank you in advance for your time.

-----UPDATE-----

Following Anna's advice I have implemented the selectAnnotation function. Here is my code.

```
            if fromSegue.type == 2 {
//              all my annotations are in an array named pinJar  
//              fromSegue is a NotificationModel passed as an argument from a previous function
            var annotJar = pinJar.filter{$0.subtitle == self.fromSegue.name}
            var annot = annotJar[0]
            Map.selectAnnotation(annot,animated: true)
            }
```

Comment: Use the MKMapView's [selectAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/selectAnnotation:animated:) method.

Comment: Could you please provide your current piece of code in order for us to help you?

Comment: Thank you very much Anna. This is exactly what I was looking for. Jerome, I really appreciate your help too. I did not know where to start. That is why I did not post any code at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create a `MKPointAnnotation` a then call the method for example

```
var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
info1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(20.646696, -103.398744)
info1.title = "Title"
info1.subtitle = "More Info"
info1.imageName = "iphonepin.png"
propMapa.addAnnotation(info1)

propMapa.selectAnnotation(info1, animated: true)
```

CustomPointAnnotation is a custom class and extends from `MKPointAnnotation`

Comment: what does this mean "You need create a MKPointAnnotation a then call the method for example"   i can create the MKPointAnnotation... but I am not seeing how that is connected with CustomPointAnnotation   Thanks

Comment: You need create a subclass MKPointAnnotation and create one object of tipe  MKPointAnnotation example:  MKPointAnnotation * data

Comment: @Fabio That last line, "selectAnnotation" is what I needed - thanks for that! Oddly though, the popover that displays when I select the annotation (when using this method) is not anchored properly. Any idea why?